# Error parsing CSV to XLS with VBA script

Tags: vba, excel, csv

This function is designed to open a CSV file, and import all the data into a specific Sheet on an Excel Workbook.

But I think there is some kind of problem I can't resolve in some cases with delimiters.

This is my function:

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder_Invenotry()

  Dim strFilename As String
  Dim wsMstr  As Worksheet:   Set wsMstr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALL_ACTIUS")

  If MsgBox("Erase sheet before start importing?", vbYesNo, "Delete?") _
= vbYes Then wsMstr.UsedRange.Clear

  strFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename _
                (FileFilter:="CSV File (*.csv), *.csv", _
                Title:="Select CSV file: ")

 Worksheets("ALL_MACHINES").Activate
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & strFilename, _
    Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 1252
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With

End Sub
```

This is part of the source code (CSV file), containing a line that is not beeing "translted" as expected:

[image]

Here you can see how this line is translated to the Excel. The 12X5" string should'nt be there. The first column should only contain IP addresses.

[image]

I'm pretty sure It's a delimiter character issue, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: I think the problem is related with a: "\n" or "\r" character. Any way to skip it?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue on Windows (though I did not line break midway of the string *Server custom ...*). When you open the file in a text editor does *12X5* start on a new line like you show in screenshot?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The 12X5 starts on a new line.

Comment: Check how data is sourced. Why does it break midway in a string instead of by data line?

Comment: this usually happens when the file is saved with Unicode Encoding instead of ASCII / UTF-8 / ANSI, so you can try saving it with ANSI or UTF-8 Encoding in Notepad

Answer (score 0):

The Workbooks.Open command worked for me with that issue.

```
Dim wb As Workbook

strFilename = "yourfilename.csv"

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFilename, local:=True)
```

Comment: If you like the results obtained with Workbooks.Open, you simply copy it : wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ALL_MACHINES").Range("A1") : 
wb.Close